# How to convert a command line table (drush output) to any spreadsheet? (csv,excel,ods)

Tags: views, chaos-tool-suite, drush

I often use commands like `drush pm-list` or drush `views-list` to get some listings of what my current project is using and for sake of usability I would like to import that stuff in a spreadsheet programm (I dont care which, csv can be imported bascially everywhere).

I digged into drush code and find out that it uses [`Console_Table`](http://pear.php.net/package/Console_Table) for generating table like output. Maybe someone has an idea how to implement/ find a generic way to get a csv output from it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out this new feature from the latest dev version of Drush 8.x-6.x:

```
$ drush @dev pm-list --format=csv
Administration,Actions permissions (VBO) (actions_permissions),Module,Not installed,7.x-3.1
Administration,Administration Development tools (admin_devel),Module,Not installed,7.x-3.0-rc4
Administration,Administration menu (admin_menu),Module,Enabled,7.x-3.0-rc4
Administration,Administration menu Toolbar style (admin_menu_toolbar),Module,Not installed,7.x-3.0-rc4
Administration,Administration views (admin_views),Module,Enabled,7.x-1.1
CCK,CCK (cck),Module,Enabled,7.x-2.x-dev
CCK,Content Migrate (content_migrate),Module,Disabled,7.x-2.x-dev
CCK,Location CCK (location_cck),Module,Enabled,7.x-3.0-alpha1
... etc.
```

If you are at all wary about using a dev version of Drush, you could check it out following the version control instructions at http://drupal.org/project/drush/git-instructions.  Then, you can use `git checkout 7.x-5.8` to go back to latest stable, and `git checkout 8.x-6.x` to go back to latest dev, and use stable most of the time, and the dev version when you want to output something in another data format.

**Update:**  Note also that Drush 8.x-6.x-rc4 is out now, which is pretty well fit for general consumption.

**Update 2:** Note that this is a standard feature now in Drush 6 and Drush 7 (master branch of Drush on github)

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting that as at this date, both the CSV and table formatted outputs won't copy/paste in a friendly fashion into a Google Spreadsheet.

Open a spreadsheet, click A1 cell and then File > Import... and load the file directly from your Desktop (eg).